# How to pass a filename as a function parameter in python?

Tags: python, file, io

I get the following error: remove_metadata() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
class Chess:
    def remove_metadata(filepath):
        with open(filepath, "r", errors="ignore") as f:
            contents = f.read()
            print(contents)
            
def main():
    c1 = Chess()
    c1.remove_metadata('chess_game.pgn')
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need to add `self`, like `def remove_metadata(self, filepath):`

Answer (score 0):

Add another parameter `self` to `remove_metadata`

```
def remove_metadata(self,filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r", errors="ignore") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        print(contents)
```